# How do I created a solid model from an imported wireframe?

Tags: faces, wireframe

I have imported a CSV file to give me vertices and edges using the addon CSV mesh Importer, but none of the edges connect. I have trying to model a ship from a video game so I can export and 3D print it. 
Is there any easy way to change wires to become faces?

[image: close up of edge]
I have tried different <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> options but they don't work.
[image: the full ship]

Comment: Please try to add some screenshots

Comment: did you mean an SVG file? if yes, your imported object is a curve, not a mesh. You can convert it to mesh using ALT-C

Comment: Basically, you are getting it imported to edges or curves, not sure which. This will be very difficult to fix. The easiest method would be to look for ways to convert the file to a standard mesh format like .obj or .fbx *before* importing.

Comment: Unless you can generate the faces in the original program, as suggested by @VRM, you need to create the faces manually.  Try selecting one vertex or edge, and then selecting linked (Alt L) and doing Alt F to "beauty fill" If the vertices are not connected try using "remove doubles" before selecting linked. In any case, you are in for a lot of manual an tedious work. Do a search for techniques for re-topologizing it might help you as well to create a new mesh using the existing vertices as reference.